# Delete keyboard button hit in GWT

Tags: gwt, keyboard-events

How would we know if "Delete" button on key board is pressed in GWT?

i tried keydown handler ,key press but i cant find methods like "isDeleteKeyDown()".

Thanks

Comment: Stick with "addKeyDownHandler" instead of the press one, and look at Nitin's answer below for what to put inside the "onKeyDown" method that you're overriding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keydown event is firing properly for you on press of delete then you can compare the keycode to figure out if the delete key has been pressed. Basically,

```
if(event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_DELETE) 
{ // Delete key pressed, do you stuff }
```